# Is it possible to search for questions that have been put on hold?

Tags: support

When I use the search bar to perform a keyword search for previous questions, is it possible (for example) to append something to my keywords so that my search will include questions that have been put on hold?

Comment: [A search like this?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes)

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems to be no direct way to only search for questions 'on hold', but one can use the search word [closed:yes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3ayes) to find all closed questions (that haven't been deleted).

For an indirect way to only search for questions 'on hold', one could try the search [closed:yes duplicate:no migrated:no](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano%20migrated%3ano).

More generally, to learn how to search, click on *Advanced Search Tips* in the right margin of the [Phys.SE search box](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search) page, or visit the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for a more complete set of search options.

Comment: Oh, that's actually... quite a lot of them. 50+ sounds reasonable but still like quite a bit.